# Facebook wall post error : OAuthException

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, post, facebook-wall

I integrated facebook login in my code successfully. Now want to POST on a wall.

**Below is the error:**

```
FBRequest didFailWithError:The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.) Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0xeaf9870 {error=<CFBasicHash 0xeaf9770 [0x20eb400]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0xead54f0 [0x20eb400]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0xead6470 [0x20eb400]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
    3 : <CFString 0xead4610 [0x20eb400]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0xead4660 [0x20eb400]>{contents = "(#200) This API call requires a valid app_id."}
    6 : <CFString 0xead4180 [0x20eb400]>{contents = "code"} = 200
}
}
```

//CODE

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/feed",[defaults objectForKey:@"FBUDID"]] 
                          andParams:variables 
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                        andDelegate:self];
```

I have checked AppID & secret key.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: It must be appid related problem only. Please check as facebook itself returns appid problem. Try to create another application and check with that appid. Or put your appid here as well so we can check that app id.

Comment: I already checked with another appid (newly created). but getting same response. Is it my problem or fb? And what do you mean by "Please check as facebook itself returns appid problem"?

Comment: Facebook never lies. Can u share your appid ? I can check.

Comment: Now i am getting this error: Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: (null)

Comment: There is something wrong in your code. I have tried posting message in one of our account. Your app is working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Jennis. can you provide me sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[params setObject:@"status" forKey:@"type"];
[params setObject:@"Write your message here to post" forKey:@"message"];
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Posting message to self (User who is logged in) wall can be done using above code. let me know in case of any query.